# Rearrange text output file

Tags: regex, r, parsing, text

I have an output text file, which looks like this

```
    2014           1          11  0.0000000E+00  0.3434822    
0.0000000E+00  0.7726533      0.9574943      -1.550000      9.9998499E-05
0.5000000      0.9999800      0.0000000E+00   1063.578      0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00
-108.9834      9.3596420E-05  5.5007441E-03  0.0000000E+00  9.9998499E-05
0.2500000      -27.04700      -18.10586      6.4020833E-06  0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  -108.9834      9.3609699E-05 -0.3065675     -0.5260010    
9.9998499E-05  6.4020833E-06  0.0000000E+00  -63.42108      0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.8130355      0.1201915      0.2232908    
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000       1.000000      0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  -63.40063      0.0000000E+00  0.5000000       20.24322    
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
-7.2759576E-12
    2014           1          11   1.000000      0.3434822    
0.0000000E+00  0.7719470      0.9573622      -1.720000      0.0000000E+00
0.5800000      0.9999800      0.0000000E+00   1060.771      0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00
-201.3443      8.9306879E-05  1.0951841E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
 0.2519612      -20.23699      -12.15771      4.2895390E-06   ...
.
.
.
```

But for working with it, e.g. in Excel I would need something looking like this:

```
   2014 1 11 0.000000 0.3434822 ...
   2014 1 11 1.000000 0.3434822 ...
   .
   .
   .
```

I tried the grep() expression in R, but couldn't get it to work yet.

Comment: What is the question ? How should the exponents be handled ? What did you try ? And WHY R ?

Comment: Was this file created in R or something else? If it was made with R, it will be much easier to manipulate the original data than to parse this text.

Comment: No the file was not created in R, it is an output file from a model. No I don't have to use R, but it is the programming language I know most about. If you have better suggestions I am happy to try them!

Comment: Do all lines of the desired output have the same number of "cells"? As a first step, you could use `scan()` to read the data as strings and then transform the vector into a matrix.

Comment: Yes, all lines have the same number of values. Ok I will try that, may I ask how to transform the vectors into matrix?

Comment: point <- scan("C:/UEBGrid/Gryt2014_workfile/Outputs /Point1file.txt",what=character())

write.table(point,"C:/UEBGrid/Gryt2014_workfile/Outputs/Point1file_R.csv",row.names=FALSE, sep=",") With that I get all the data as one column, how should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: You have a vector with string values after `point <- scan(...)`, right? So something like `dim( point ) <- c( noOfRows, noOfCols )` should help.

Comment: Hey thanks, I think I am close to solving this problem! Thanks for all the great input, so far! When I have the finished script I will upload it her.